# How to parse a comma separated list of variables to use in string comparison?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parsing, recursion, ssms

Currently we have dynamic code that inputs an unknown number of values from a UI as individual variables, e.g., user inputs "tigers", "lions", and "bear" this creates 3 string parameters

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE_1 AS VARCHAR(6) = 'tigers';
DECLARE @VARIABLE_2 AS VARCHAR(5) = 'lions';
DECLARE @VARIABLE_3 AS VARCHAR(4) = 'bears';
```

These variables are then input to query where we have the variable placeholder as a comma seperate list i.e.,`@VARIABLE_1,@VARIABLE_2,@VARIABLE_3`, which we typically use with parentheses and an IN statement:

```
WHERE TABLE.COLUMN IN (@VARIABLE_1,@VARIABLE_2,@VARIABLE_3)
```

However, we'd like to use the variables in a string comparison appending wildcards to both ends rather than exact match:

```
WHERE TABLE.COLUMN LIKE '%'+@VARIABLE_1+'%'
      OR TABLE.COLUMN LIKE '%'+@VARIABLE_2+'%'
      OR TABLE.COLUMN LIKE '%'+@VARIABLE_3+'%'
```

This would return us data like the below:

| ID | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Detriot Tigers |
| 2 | Detroit Lions |
| 4 | Lions and Tigers and Bears oh My! |
| 7 | Brown Bears |

The way the parameters are input into the SQL query is always the same (i.e., a comma separated list of variables) but the number of variables can change based on user input. Is there a way to use SQL/T-SQL to break out the list to do the string comparison (utilizing SSMS 18)?

I've Tried using a WHILE loop and STUFF, however, I realize that only works for parsing strings not a list of variables (`{{C_PARAMETER}}` is the placeholder where the variable list is input:

```
WITH cteRecursion(SomeID, OtherID, SingleParam, ParamList) AS
(
    SELECT
        SomeID,
        OtherID,
        LEFT(, CHARINDEX(',', {{C_PARAMETER}} + ',') - 1),
        STUFF({{C_PARAMETER}}, 1, CHARINDEX(',', {{C_PARAMETER}} + ','), '')
    FROM Testdata
    WHERE column like '%'+LEFT(, CHARINDEX(',', {{C_PARAMETER}} + ',') - 1)+'%'
    
    UNION all

    SELECT
        SomeID,
        OtherID,
        LEFT(ParamList, CHARINDEX(',', ParamList + ',') - 1),
        STUFF(ParamList, 1, CHARINDEX(',', ParamList + ','), '')
    FROM cteRecursion
    WHERE
        column like '%'+LEFT(ParamList, CHARINDEX(',',  ParamList + ',') - 1)+'%'
      AND  ParamList > ''
)
```

We could also build a single parameter for each string we want to do a comparison on, but then that decreases the ease of use for the end user.

Hoping to do this in SQL if at all possible! Thanks!

Comment: assuming you are using a stored procedure...

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You should read about using table valued parameters instead of delimited lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating things. If you can just pass a simpler list to the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC dbo.procedure @param nvarchar(max) = N'tigers, lions, bears';
```

Then you can just say:

```
SELECT src.* 
  FROM dbo.TestData AS src
  INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@param, N', ') AS p
  ON src.[column] LIKE N'%' + RTRIM(p.value) + N'%';
```

You might also consider [table-valued parameters](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql), where you can just pass in a table that you don't have to split at all (and then don't have to worry about, say, commas in the input). But there are other solutions, too, e.g. [`OPENJSON`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6990/sql-performance-splitting-comma-separated-strings-tvp-tvf-openjson-stringsplit/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Answer (score 0):

A minimal reproducible example is not provided.

Here is a conceptual example for you. It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.

A number of searched words is '*unlimited*' via comma separated parameter:

```
@searchFor VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Tigers,Panthers';
```

The solution is using XQuery's Quantified Expressions.

For the reference: [Quantified Expressions (XQuery)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/quantified-expressions-xquery?view=sql-server-ver16)

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('Detroit Tigers'),
('Detroit Lions'),
('Lions and Tigers and Bears oh My!'),
('Brown Bears'),
('Florida Panthers');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ','
   , @searchFor VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Tigers,Panthers';

;WITH rs AS
(
SELECT *
   , c.value('some $r in /root/source/r/text()
         satisfies contains(data(/root/target)[1], $r)', 'BIT') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><source><r><![CDATA[' 
   + REPLACE(@searchFor, @Separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></source>'
   + '<target><r><![CDATA[' 
   + REPLACE(tokens, SPACE(1), ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></target></root>' AS XML)
   ) AS t1(c)
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE Result = 1;
```

**Output**

| id | tokens |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Detroit Tigers |
| 3 | Lions and Tigers and Bears oh My! |
| 5 | Florida Panthers |